# How do I create an iPhone screenshot with the metal chrome around it

Tags: ios, iphone, screenshot

Anyone familiar with the old iOS Simulator from ~ 2/3 years ago, it included the (black or white) metal Chrome around the simulator.

[image]

This allowed you to take screenshots with the Chrome around it, which made for nice looking app store demo screenshots.

Is there an automatic way to do this, or a service that allows you to upload your screens and does it automatically? -- Otherwise I would have to resort to taking a screenshot, then adding the Chrome around it using something like [Teehan & Lax's iPhone GUI PSD](http://www.teehanlax.com/tools/iphone/) -- which is a lot of manual work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link : https://developer.apple.com/app-store/marketing/guidelines/#images. In the second part of that passage there are some links to download different chromes image.

Answer (score 0):

I did it for http://mobilito.net/: use a picture of an iPhone as a background image an put your screenshot as an image on top of it. You just have to get the right dimension for the image to fit the screen on  your iPhone picture.

Answer (score 0):

Felix Krause has an [excellent command line tool](https://github.com/fastlane/frameit) for this, go take a look.